# How to display data from an array which contains composite data by using foreach in knockout bindings

Tags: html, knockout.js

Hi someone can help me to solve the following issue. I get an array contains employees in companies by using ajax and I try to display data, unfortunately anything is displayed. Below snippet code.

```
var companyArray = {
    companies: [
        {
          id: 1, name: contoso1, 
          employees [
            {id: 10, fistname: dupond, lastname: azex, department: admin},
            {id: 10, fistname: pickoli, lastname: verne, department: computing},
            .
            .
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 2, name: contoso2, 
          employees:[
           {id:10, fistname: dupond2, lastname: azex2, department: admin, photo: uri},
           {id:10, fistname: pickoli2, lastname: verne2, department: computing, photo:uri},
           .
           .
          ]
        },
        .
        .
    ],
};
```

Ajax request:

```
var companiesArray = ko.observableArray();

$.ajax({
   url: "remote url",         
   cache: false,
   type: "GET",
   dataType: "json",
   headers: getSecurityHeaders(),

}).done(function (data) {
  $.each(data, function (index, value) {
     companiesArray.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(value));
  }      
});
```

Display on html page

```
<div class="row" data-bind='template: { name: "companyTmpl", foreach: companiesArray }'>
</div>
<script id="companyTmpl" type="text/html">
  <div class="col-md-2-1">
    <article>
       <h3>$data.name</h3>
       <div data-bind='attr:{ id: "company" + $index() + 1}' class="company-wrapper">
          <div class="employee_wrapper">
             <ul data-bind="foreach: $data.employees">
                <li><span data-bind:'text: firstname +" " + lastname'></span></li>
                <li><span data-bind:'text: department'></span></li>
                <li><img data-bind='attr:{src: photo'/></li>
              </ul>
          </div>

       </div>
    </article>
 </div>
</script>
```

Thank you for your help.

PMD.

Comment: So where is the line where you apply the bindings? Could it be you forgot that? Also, your code sample has a syntax error, please fix that first.

Comment: The bindings are applied like this: var app = new AppViewModel(new AppDataModel()); and var companiesArray = ko.observableArray(); is defined like this: self.companiesArray = ko.observableArray(); inside AppDataModel.

Comment: There are a number is issues with the code above.  Allowing for JSON formatting ( like strings ) issues, the HTML also has problems `data-bind:'text...`. ( should be '=' not ':' ).   Correctly these obvious issues, I get items successful rendered (http://jsfiddle.net/HSDLU/).  The only other cause might be the nesting of your models.  What is the ambient object at your `<div class="row">`.  ( check using `ko.dataFor` ).  Can you post the relevant HTML showing the DOM structure from the root where your applyBindings is targeted

Comment: One more point to verify: the hierarchy of your data. Your view expects, ie, that the "employees" be at "companiesArray[x].employees", but your viewmodel isn't in this structure. The current structure is "companiesArray.companies[x].employees".